# nmcli no longer allow settings modification?

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager

When I try to modify network manager settings with nmcli, it says

`Error: 'con' command 'modify' is not valid.`

So if `nmcli con modify XXX` command is no longer supported, what is the substitute?

**EDIT**

nmcli version: `nmcli tool, version 0.9.8.8`

networkmanager version:  `networkmanager 0.9.8.8-1`

I'm running Arch Linux

Comment: What version of NM do you have? In what distribution? What does the man page say?

Comment: @Gilles updated question. I googled and found the `modify` command, but man page says nothing about it

Comment: What are you trying to do? My `nmcli` here (`NetworkManager-0.9.8.8-2.fc19.x86_64`, Fedora 19) also doesn't know of `con modify`.

Comment: @vonbrand modify settings, e.g gateway ip address of a VPN connection

Comment: @vonbrand I need to do this from command line, I'm making an automated script

Comment: afaik, `nmcli` never supported modifying settings... what about `delete` old one and `add` a new one? I am  not sure about this, because there is a `delete` subcommand but not for `add`

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/872507/what-is-the-new-syntax-for-nmcli-show-and-nmcli-modify - looks like `modify` is in newer versions of `nmcli`

Answer (score 0):

Here (Fedora 19) I have a `nm-connection-editor` tool that permits reconfiguring connections. It is graphics-only. To reconfigure network settings by CLI/script, you'd use `nmcli nm ...`.

Comment: Hmm, when I try `nmcli nm --help` (version 0.9.8.8), it says it only supports `COMMAND := { status | permissions | enable | sleep | wifi | wwan }`